# Why was "How to setup a connection to Redis Sentinel using Jedis library?" closed as looking for a tool?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed, recommendation-questions

The off topic closing reason should be clear, but it isn't for me for this question:
[How to setup a connection to Redis Sentinel using Jedis library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382065/how-to-setup-a-connection-to-redis-sentinel-using-jedis-library)
It is clearly stated in the title that the developper already choosed his library: jedis, but is requiring the small part of code to use it.

It should be clear to me that "seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries" is about asking for which library to use, but not for how to use it: in Java 80% of questions are about using libraries which is quite logical, the language is extensible and you can do nearly nothing if you don't use any library at all for HTTP, SQL.. every frequent usages of a web server.

Comment: The [initial revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19382065/revisions) of that question do seem very unclear, the post was edited to ask a more specific question after the closure specifically. Just cast a reopen vote and send it to the reopen votes queue.

Comment: And even then, it was closed almost __5 years ago__, and it's still a low-quality question, that IMO certainly doesn't match today's standards.

Comment: It's also been through the reopen review queue _twice_, and voted to stay closed both times... I think it's a little excessive to drag this to Meta.

Comment: I couldn't see that. Btw its the only question/answer on this topic. I think that redis is still used, even **5 years** laters.

Comment: I still use an oven to bake a cake. That doesn't make questions about ovens more or less on-topic. The problem with this question is that it lacks any form of research. It might as well still be a request for an off-site resource, just worded differently.

Comment: That's a better argument indeed - "lacks form of research" I can understand that

Comment: @pdem, you should be able to see attempts of reopening in [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19382065/timeline) (second image under vote buttons on post page).

Comment: Also there you'll see that it was closed before last edit, and can go through a link to see changes applied by that last edit.

Answer (score 7):

My challenge with a question like this is that it doesn't really define *success*.

Yes, you can connect to Redis Sentinel with this library, but what does that really entail?

- That you can just access it through the library?
- That you can push data to it?
- That it's available through a firewall?
- That the connection is pooled in the event of a network blip, or high transaction load?
- Is there an expectation that this also work with non-clustered, non-HA Redis as well?

The other factor to this is that it doesn't identify a *specific* issue with the OP's original attempt to connect through this library.  Is the OP having a challenge with this just because it's this specific library, or is it due to something else?  We're not informed.

Lastly, this point is bifurcated, but I need to make it anyway:

- In the time since the OP posted this question, the documentation has improved.
- If the documentation of a library is terrible, a different library will inevitably be selected.

So my thoughts on keeping a question like this around are, it doesn't really add to the wealth of knowledge or guides out there (just a Google of "Jedis" is enough to give me plenty of useful guides from reputable sources), and [it invites people to say, "What about *this* library instead??"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39743947/1079354)

I don't really see a viable future for this question here.  Sure, it's got upvotes and everything, and people are like, interested in that, but it's not a *good* question.